# How to remove remaining unwanted char from a string

Tags: c#, string, char, output, trim

My string output is

```
String mystring="My Name¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥";
```

How do i take that ¥¥¥¥¥¥ out of my word.
Im using C#.

I tried this

```
mystring.Trim( '¥' );
```

but it didnt work

Im making a chat and this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace Chat
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        textLocalIp.Text= GetLocalIP();
        textFriendsIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
    }

     private string GetLocalIP()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }


     private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        try
        {
            int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                string c = Caesar(receivedMessage, -1); // String recibido se cambia alreves
                //Console.WriteLine(c.Trim( new Char[] { '¥' } )); //Here is where it doesnt work////////////////////

                listMessage.Items.Add("Anonymous: "+c.Trim(  '¥'  ));


            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer,
                0,
                buffer.Length,
                SocketFlags.None,
                ref epRemote,
                new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack),
                buffer);



        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

            string b = Caesar(textMessage.Text, 1); // Sending the Chipper


            byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
            msg = enc.GetBytes(b);

            sck.Send(msg);
            listMessage.Items.Add("You: "+textMessage.Text);
            textMessage.Clear();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            //epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);

            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textFriendsIp.Text),
                Convert.ToInt32(textFriendsPort.Text));
            sck.Connect(epRemote);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer,
                0,
                buffer.Length,
                SocketFlags.None,
                ref epRemote,
                new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack),
                buffer);

            button1.Text = "Connected!";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            textMessage.Focus();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }


static string Caesar(string value, int shift)
    {
    char[] buffer = value.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        // Letter.
        char letter = buffer[i];
        // Add shift to all.
        letter = (char)(letter + shift);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
    if (letter > 'z')
    {
    letter = (char)(letter - 26);
    }
    else if (letter < 'a')
    {
    letter = (char)(letter + 26);
    }
    // Store.
    buffer[i] = letter;
}
return new string(buffer);
}

}
```

}

The error is where i marked it, and my out put is coming out like My Name¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥¥ so i just want to separate it

Comment: mystring.Trim(  '¥'  ) i tried this

Comment: What was the result? Can you show some more code? It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Seems to work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/bYPq6T

Comment: When you call `EndReceiveFrom` you get the number of bytes received returned in `size`. Unfortunately, you don't limit the data that you take from `receivedData` to that length, hence the unexpected data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you expect the variable to have the new value, you need to make sure you assign the result back to it:

```
mystring = mystring.Trim( '¥' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your might try

```
mystring = mystring.Remove(mystring.IndexOf('¥'));
```

I believe that will remove everything after the first instance of that character.  Find documentation here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I think it can be used with just one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to remove the trailing character.

As per [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The TrimEnd method removes from the current string all trailing
>   characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation
>   stops when the first character that is not in trimChars is encountered
>   at the end of the string.

```
mystring = mystring.TrimEnd( '¥' );
```